# Arduino reduces the laser power

Tags: arduino

Its important to mention that I'm noob. I bought 500mw 405nm TTL module laser(5-12 volt) driver circuit. When I supplied laser with 12 volt, it turns on with max power. but when i connects laser TTL module to arduino (pin 11) in order to control turning on & off of laser through GRBL(CNC machine language) command with full power, the output of laser reduces.

"M05 S0" turns off the laser while "M03 S255" should turns on the laser with full power as it is turning on with direct 12 volt supply, but its not happening.

so how can I make laser turn on with full power with arduino control?

Laser I,m using https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B071J2W7V8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Laser driver circuit
[image]

Comment: Did the module come with any documentation? If so, have you read it?

Comment: Your Amazon link is to the ad. We need a link to the datasheet. Advice here is "No datasheet - no sale." Can you find a datasheet?

Comment: are you running any kind of code on the arduino?

Comment: Laser did not come with any data sheet.

I'm using GRBL command to run arduino.

Comment: Also asked at: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/51081 and http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=537202 If you're going to do that then at least be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.